# Can I mix different branded pex pipe with different branded pex fittings?

Tags: plumbing

I recently paid a plumber to redo my house in pex & he ended up doing the lot in sharkbite pipe & their push to connect fittings.
I’ve read too many stories of leaks in various blogs that I feel uncomfortable sealing them up in the wall.
My question is: can I still use the sharkbite pex pipe with an auspex copper crimp fitting instead?
(FYI I’m from Australia & they don’t have any sharkbite crimp fittings available here).

Comment: I think there is more than one type of PEX pipe(A and B maybe), so if the fittings are made for that type of pipe/pex it should not matter what name/type they are, they should work.

Comment: If the job specified pex and crimp fittings you should have demanded he use what was specified in the contract.  If not, at least try to get a warranty against leakage from labor and materials for at least a year.